# post dynamic foms to db

Tags: php, javascript, sql

I'm using dynamic forms in my project, the input field's id increments by 1 each time a new field set is called:

```
 <input type="text" id="billing_id1" />
 <input type="text" id="billing_id2" />
```

In the processor how would I go about submitting all data, because the following code is only submitting the first field set...

processor:

```
$billing_id = empty($_POST['billing_id']) ? die ("ERROR: Billing ID was not submitted") : mysql_escape_string($_POST['billing_id']);

$connection = mysql_connect($mysql_server, $mysql_user, $mysql_pass) or die("Could not connect to database");

mysql_select_db($mysql_db) or ("Unable to select database");

$query = "INSERT INTO customer_contacts (billing_id) VALUES ('$billing_id')";

$result = mysql_query($query) or die ("ERROR: $query. ".mysql_error());
```

Hope someone can help, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use square brackets instead:

```
<input type="text" id="billing_ids[]" />
<input type="text" id="billing_ids[]" />
```

You'll get an array instead of individual values

```
// $billing_ids == array('val1', 'val2');
foreach($billing_ids AS $id) {
    $query = "INSERT INTO customer_contacts (billing_id) VALUES ('$id')";
    $result = mysql_query($query) or die ("ERROR: $query. ".mysql_error());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're checking for `billing_id` when you have no field named `billing_id`, then you should receive your error message. You'll probably find it easier to use an array. If you add `[]` the end of each field name, then each element of `$_POST` named liked this will be an array. You can then loop over each of those.

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="text" id="billing_id[]" />
<input type="text" id="billing_id[]" />
```

Then on your processing page:

```
foreach($_POST["billing_id"] as $key=>$value){
    mysql_query("INSERT INTO customer_contacts(billing_id) VALUES('".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["billing_id"][$key])."')";
}
```